# Checking proof that that a sequence of integrals converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $g\in L^1[0,\infty)$ and $g\geq0$, then $$lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N\frac{x}{N}g(x)dx=0$$

My idea for the proof is as follows.

First, we have that
$$\int_0^N\frac{x}{N}g(x)dx\leq\int g(x)dx$$
So I only have to show that the sequence of functions $$\frac{x}{N}g(x)1_{[0,N]}\to_{a.e} 0$$

I do this by contradiction, I assume the opposite so there must be a set $E$ with positive measure and an $\alpha$ such that $$\frac{x}{N}g(x)1_{[0,N]}\geq \alpha$$

But this implies that $$\int g\geq N\int_E\frac{\alpha}{x}$$
But this is a contradiction to the fact that $g\in L^1$, because the right side goes to infinity as the integral is a constant.

Is this proof correct? If it is, is there something that needs extra justification?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you want to apply Dominated convergence Therem. For this you have to replace $\int_0^N\frac{x}{N}g(x)dx\leq\int g(x)dx$ with $\frac{x}{N}g(x)\chi_{(0,N)}\leq g(x)$ pointwise.

The fact that $\frac{x}{N}g(x)\chi_{(0,N)} \to 0$ a.e. hardly requires a proof. This is because **for every $x$** this quantity is bounded by $\frac C N $ where $C=xg(x)$. So the convergence is everywhere, not just almost evreywhere.